# spring data mongodb: sum aggregation by domain name

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have collection which is contain id, domain . In the collection the same domain saved multiple times. I want  to aggregate and get result like

google.com 4 
times.com 5

My code

```
 public List<DomainDTO> domainAggregation() {

        Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(
                group(fields("id","domain")),
                group("domain").count().as("count"),
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, previousOperation(), "domain")
        );


        AggregationResults groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                pipeline, Domains.class, DomainDTO.class);

        List<DomainDTO> domainReport = groupResults.getMappedResults();

        return domainReport;
    }
```

DomainDTO consist

```
 private String domain;    
    private Integer count;
```

Domain entity consist

```
 private String id;  
    private String searchId;    
    private String domain;
    private Date searchDate;
    private String searchName;
    private Integer count;
```

Result json is

```
{
    "domain": null,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "domain": null,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "domain": null,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "domain": null,
    "count": 48
  },
```

Domain name is not passed, and not sorted. Could not find bug. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query outputs something like

```
{ "$group" : { 
   "_id" : { "id" : "$id" , "domain" : "$domain"}
} } , 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id.domain" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}} , 
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : -1 , "_id.domain" : -1}}
```

I believe you're intending something like

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$domain" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}} , 
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : -1}}
```

Aggregation Java Code:

```
Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(
   group("domain").count().as("count"),
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, previousOperation())
);
```

You will need a `$project` stage to map _id back to `domain` in your `DomainDTO` class.

```
Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(
   group("domain").count().as("count"),
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, previousOperation()),
   project(bind("domain", "_id")).andExclude("_id").andInclude("count")
);
```

Mongo Shell

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$domain" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}} , 
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : -1}},                   
{ "$project" : { "domain" : "$_id" , "_id" : 0 , "count" : 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, any time I did before with mongo java api, but did not understand how to do it with spring data.

Comment: finally it looks
 Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(
                group("domain").count().as("count"),
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count"),
                project(bind("domain", "_id")).andExclude("_id").andInclude("count")
        );